# Reduce stream of Flux to Flux

Tags: spring-boot, stream, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am having some problems with applying to reduce operation on `Stream<Flux<T>>`, I would like to reduce it to `Flux<T>`. Each AdProvider provides offers as Flux, I would like to use the stream to get all offers from each one of them and concatenate them to one pipeline. How could I possibly do that with reduce?

```
Set<AdProvider> adProviders;

@Override
@LogBefore
public void gather()
{
    adProviders
        .parallelStream()
        .map(this::gatherOffers)
        .reduce(?)
        .subscribe();
}

private Flux<Ad> gatherOffers(AdProvider adProvider)
{
    try
    {
        return adProvider.offers();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.warn(EXCEPTION_WHILE_PROCESSING_OFFERS, adProvider.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);

        return Flux.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Flatten `Stream<Flux>` using `Flux#fromStream()` + `Flux#flatMap()`

In order to solve the problem, you may combine `Flux#fromStream()` (which convert `Stream<Flux>` to `Flux<Flux>`) and `Flux#flatMap()` (which flatten inner fluxes to flat `Flux`) as in the following example:

```
Set<AdProvider> adProviders;

@Override
public void gather()
{
    Flux.fromStream(adProviders.stream())
        .parallel() // replace .parallelStream with separate parallel + runOn
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(this::gatherOffers)
        .subscribe();
}

private Flux<Ad> gatherOffers(AdProvider adProvider)
{
    try
    {
        return adProvider.offers();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.warn(EXCEPTION_WHILE_PROCESSING_OFFERS, adProvider.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);

        return Flux.empty();
    }
}
```

As it might be noticed, I replaced `parallelStream` with plain `.stream` and `parallel` + `runOn` which do almost the same.

Alternatively, you may avoid using stream at all and simply rely on `Flux.fromIterble` + the same `Flux#flatMap`:

```
Set<AdProvider> adProviders;

@Override
public void gather()
{
    Flux.fromIterable(adProviders)
        .parallel() // replace .parallelStream with separate parallel + runOn
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(this::gatherOffers)
        .subscribe();
}

private Flux<Ad> gatherOffers(AdProvider adProvider)
{
    try
    {
        return adProvider.offers();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.warn(EXCEPTION_WHILE_PROCESSING_OFFERS, adProvider.getClass().getSimpleName(), e);

        return Flux.empty();
    }
}
```